# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0]

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Following is the problematic line of build.gradle:

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

Comment: Could you provide any additional error messages?

Answer (score 1):

**Implementation is not found.**

`build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

---

1. Go to `Build`.
2. Open `Clean Project`.
3. `Build`->`Clean Project`.
4. `Rebuild the Project`.

Check : [Getting started with Material Components for Android](https://m2.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started), [Material Design](https://m3.material.io/).